# Why does a form with an input text-box and a button which calls a javascript function on enter key press?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<form action="">
<input id="user_input" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('okButton').click()" >
<input id="okButton" type="button" onclick="JS_function();" value="OK">
</form>
```

I want to be able to click the button by pressing enter while inside the text-box. With my code the button is clicked when i press enter inside the text-box, BUT immediately after the page is refreshed and everything restarts, any ideas why and how to prevent it?

Comment: And your code shall set you free!

Comment: What do you mean? When I press enter the page refreshes against my will.

Comment: try to return false after executing the function to avoid form submits

Comment: Either I don't understand what you mean or it's not working. How do you mean exactly, should I add: return false; at the end of the function?

Comment: check the answer of : Christofer Eliasson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that pressing the Enter-key will trigger the form to post. Since you have an empty action-attribute, the form will post to the current page, which looks like a reload.

To prevent the browsers default behaviour to post the form on Enter, try to return `false` from your onKeyDown-callback.

```
if(event.keyCode == 13) { document.getElementById('okButton').click(); return false; }
```

You could also call the `.preventDefault()` method on the event, which will do the same thing.

**A way to simplify and clarify:**

Since a click on the okButton will call `JS_function()`, instead of triggering a click-event on the button, you could call `JS_function()` directly from your onKeyDown-event instead.

```
<input id="user_input" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { JS_function(); return false; }" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your onKeyDown

```
if(event.keyCode == 13){event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('okButton').click();}
```

It will stop the default action of posting and let you do your stuff like clicking the ok button.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! You are amazing!! I have spent hours looking for a simple solution and this is it! Thanks man.

Comment: Please mark his post as the answer.  Don't feel bad about getting stuck for hours, you probably learned a lot.